# read csv five with array cols in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, tidyr

*my CSV  file  is like this*

col3 and col4 is always  the same length ;

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
1,2,"[1,2,3]","[1.2,2.3,2.1]"
1,3,"[1,2]","[2.5,2.6]"
2,1,"[1,2,3,4]","[1,2,3,4,5]"
3,1,"[10]","[-0.2]"
```

this is my data structure

```
structure(list(col1 = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L), col2 = c(2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L), col3 = c("[1,2,3]", "[1,2]", "[1,2,3,4]", "[10]"), col4 = c("[1.2,2.3,2.1]", 
"[2.5,2.6]", "[1,2,3,4,5]", "[-0.2]")), row.names = c(NA, -4L
), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x323ce50>)
```

*I need data after unnesting like this*

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
1,2,1,1.2
1,2,2,2.3
1,2,3,2.1
1,3,1,2.5
1,3,2,2.6
....
```

what should I do for this data?

Comment: fast reading these kind of data without extra post processing will be available in data.table's `fread` function, for status of that FR see/upvote here https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1162

Comment: worth to note that writing of these kind of data is already available in data.table's `fwrite`

Answer (score 1):

Remove `[]` from the data and use `separate_rows` on `col3` and `col4` to get them in long format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(c(col3,col4), ~gsub('\\[|\\]', '', .))) %>%
  #mutate_at(vars(c(col3,col4)), ~gsub('\\[|\\]', '', .))
  separate_rows(col3, col4, convert = TRUE, sep = ',')

#  col1  col2  col3  col4
#  <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
#1     1     2     1   1.2
#2     1     2     2   2.3
#3     1     2     3   2.1
#4     1     3     1   2.5
#5     1     3     2   2.6
#6     2     1     1   1  
#7     2     1     2   2  
#8     2     1     3   3  
#9     2     1     4   4
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(col1 = c(1L, 1L, 2L), col2 = c(2L, 3L, 1L), 
      col3 = c("[1,2,3]", "[1,2]", "[1,2,3,4]"), col4 = c("[1.2,2.3,2.1]",
      "[2.5,2.6]", "[1,2,3,4]")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: thanks very much, but I can't find `across` from my local library, my dev environment is offline, i instead it use simply code

Comment: `across` is available in `dplyr` 1.0.0 or higher. If you have the older version use `mutate_at`, replace the 2nd line with  `mutate_at(vars(c(col3,col4)), ~gsub('\\[|\\]', '', .))`. Keep `separate_rows` line as it is.

Comment: i have one col3 or col4  is only  one element,so  progress report all nested columns must same length

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. What do you mean? Can you provide a reproducible example using `dput` so that it is clear how is your data is formatted.

Comment: I update the question, your answer can't handle  my new data frame at the fourth row

Comment: @SummersKing Can you please add data using `dput`. See how I have added the data at the bottom of my answer which anyone can copy and use it in directly in R.

Comment: @SummersKing Also my answer still works for this data `df <- structure(list(col1 = c(1L, 1L, 2L), col2 = c(2L, 3L, 1L), col3 = c("[1,2,3]", 
"[1,2]", "[10]"), col4 = c("[1.2,2.3,2.1]", "[2.5,2.6]", "[0.2]"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))` which is similar to what you have in 4th row. So if my answer doesn't work on your data there is something different in your data which we need to figure out hence adding it as `dput` would help.

Comment: I am so sorry for my careless and my terrible English expression.  I update my question.   the bug happened cause of  negative element, i guess.   thanks for your help

Comment: @SummersKing No problem. In your `dput` example 3rd row has unequal elements 4 and 5. If you correct that and use my updated answer with `sep = ','` it should work.